# Auto mounting an SDHC card on Ubuntu during boot

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have the following entry in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/mmcblk1 /home ext3   default 0 2
```

Now my problem is that the device at `/dev/mmcblk1` changes its location periodically. When I set up the mount on boot, it was at location `/dev/mmcblk0`.

Is there a way to predetermine where the dive is going to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write a `udev` rule for your device, check [`this`](http://www.debianhelp.org/node/9937) article for examples, its just a one liner.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem of a device that changes location.

Comment: Because you don't have to give full path you can do /dev/mmcblk*

Comment: Ah yes... Although that seems like more of a workaround than a solution, and may have side effects if another card is added.

Answer (score 3):

You could mount by UUID rather than location:

1. Run `sudo blkid` and note down your device's UUID. The line should look something like `/dev/mmcblk1: UUID="053b91eb-19c4-4684-be81-ee758579f034" TYPE="ext3"`, where `053b91eb-19c4-4684-be81-ee758579f034` would be the UUID.
2. Replace the location in FStab with the UUID. The FStab line should now look something like `UUID=053b91eb-19c4-4684-be81-ee758579f034 /home ext3   default 0 2`

   Note: according to [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html), the options field (the fourth field on the line)
   should be `defaults` rather than `default`.

This should recognize your card regardless of location.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [PySDM](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/) if you aren't looking to manually edit configuration files.

> PySDM is a Storage Device Manager that
>   allows full customization of hard disk
>   mountpoints without manually access to
>   fstab. It also allows the creation of
>   udev rules for dynamic configuration
>   of storage devices.
>   [image]

In Ubuntu, it can be installed by searching the Ubuntu Software Center for "pysdm". Once installed, it is available under the System --> Administration --> Storage Device Manager.